# DataServiceContext ignoring navigation property when creating new entity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, dynamics-crm, navigation-properties

I am trying out the oData DataServiceContext to push data into the oData web api for Dynamics CRM 2016, but it keeps failing because it is omitting navigation properties. In this scenario I am trying to create an user that has a navigation property to a business unit that already exists. I set the property to that entity and try to persist it, but the context ignores the navigation property all together. Here is the code:

```
var user = new Systemuser()
{
   Businessunitid = businessUnit,
   Domainname = "...",
   Firstname = "...,
   Lastname = "...,
   Fullname = "...",
   Internalemailaddress = "..."
};

_context.AddToSystemusers(user);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

When it sends, I captured the POST in Fiddler and noticed it was missing:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser",
  "domainname": "COMPANY\\UserName",
  "firstname": "Emilee",
  "fullname": "Emilee Scott",
  "lastname": "Scott"  
}
```

This fails because it requires this navigation property for Businessunit is missing and I have no idea why. I was able to take the request in fiddler and modify it to have the navigation property and it works like this:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemuser",
  "businessunitid@odata.bind": "/businessunits(aa57c55b-3dae-e511-80d3-005056a7260b)",
  "domainname": "COMPANY\\UserName",
  "firstname": "Emilee",
  "fullname": "Emilee Scott",
  "lastname": "Scott"  
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I generated these entities using the oData v4 Client Code Generator.

Comment: Did you try CrmSvcUtil.exe to generate entities? Not sure, but I think it isn't converting Business Unit property properly because it is a lookup type of column in Dynamics 365 (CRM). If you already got this resolved please share your findings for others, that would be helpful.